# Kotlin i.inc() 10x slower than i++?

Tags: kotlin

So today I learned about the num.inc() feature in kotlin and decided to implement it in my code. Needless to say, that added 10x the latency time to my code (went from ~400ms to 4000+ms)

Here is the example with my traditional way (i++, 400ms)

```
package com.beaudoin

import java.io.BufferedWriter
import java.io.FileInputStream
import java.io.FileWriter
import java.nio.channels.FileChannel

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val s = System.currentTimeMillis()

    val channel = FileInputStream("client.dll").channel
    val buffer = channel.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, 0, channel.size())
    val data = ByteArray(buffer.capacity())
    buffer.get(data)

    val writer = BufferedWriter(FileWriter("dump.txt", false))
    val bytes = ByteArray(16)

    var offset = 0
    var i = 0
    while (i < data.size) {
        for (j in bytes.indices) {
            bytes[j] = data[i++]
        }
        writer.write(HexRow(offset, bytes).toString())
        writer.newLine()
        offset += 16
    }

    writer.close()

    println(System.currentTimeMillis() - s)
}

private val HEX_ARRAY = "0123456789ABCDEF".toCharArray()
private val bytes = ByteArray(4);

class HexRow(val offset: Int, val values: ByteArray) {

    fun bytesToChar(bytes: ByteArray, width: Int): CharArray {
        val hexChars = CharArray((bytes.size * 2) + (bytes.size / width))

        for (i in bytes.indices) {
            val v = bytes[i].toInt() and 0xFF
            val idx = (i * 2) + i / width

            hexChars[idx] = HEX_ARRAY[v.ushr(4)]
            hexChars[idx + 1] = HEX_ARRAY[v and 0x0F]
            if (idx + 2 < hexChars.size) {
                hexChars[idx + 2] = ' '
            }
        }
        return hexChars;
    }

    fun bytesToHex(value: Int) = String(bytesToChar(toByteArray(value), 6))

    fun bytesToHex(bytes: ByteArray) = String(bytesToChar(bytes, 1))

    fun toByteArray(value: Int): ByteArray {
        bytes[0] = value.ushr(24).toByte()
        bytes[1] = value.ushr(16).toByte()
        bytes[2] = value.ushr(8).toByte()
        bytes[3] = value.toByte()
        return bytes
    }

    override fun toString() = bytesToHex(offset) + " " + bytesToHex(values)

}
```

and here is the code using i.inc() (4000ms+)

```
package com.beaudoin

import java.io.BufferedWriter
import java.io.FileInputStream
import java.io.FileWriter
import java.nio.channels.FileChannel

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val s = System.currentTimeMillis()

    val channel = FileInputStream("client.dll").channel
    val buffer = channel.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, 0, channel.size())
    val data = ByteArray(buffer.capacity())
    buffer.get(data)

    val writer = BufferedWriter(FileWriter("dump.txt", false))
    val bytes = ByteArray(16)

    var offset = 0
/*  var i = 0
    while (i < data.size) {
        for (j in bytes.indices) {
            bytes[j] = data[i++]
        }
        writer.write(HexRow(offset, bytes).toString())
        writer.newLine()
        offset += 16
    }*/

    for (i in data.indices) {
        for (j in bytes.indices) {
            bytes[j] = data[i]
            i.inc()
        }
        writer.write(HexRow(offset, bytes).toString())
        writer.newLine()
        offset += 16
    }

    writer.close()

    println(System.currentTimeMillis() - s)
}

private val HEX_ARRAY = "0123456789ABCDEF".toCharArray()
private val bytes = ByteArray(4);

class HexRow(val offset: Int, val values: ByteArray) {

    fun bytesToChar(bytes: ByteArray, width: Int): CharArray {
        val hexChars = CharArray((bytes.size * 2) + (bytes.size / width))

        for (i in bytes.indices) {
            val v = bytes[i].toInt() and 0xFF
            val idx = (i * 2) + i / width

            hexChars[idx] = HEX_ARRAY[v.ushr(4)]
            hexChars[idx + 1] = HEX_ARRAY[v and 0x0F]
            if (idx + 2 < hexChars.size) {
                hexChars[idx + 2] = ' '
            }
        }
        return hexChars;
    }

    fun bytesToHex(value: Int) = String(bytesToChar(toByteArray(value), 6))

    fun bytesToHex(bytes: ByteArray) = String(bytesToChar(bytes, 1))

    fun toByteArray(value: Int): ByteArray {
        bytes[0] = value.ushr(24).toByte()
        bytes[1] = value.ushr(16).toByte()
        bytes[2] = value.ushr(8).toByte()
        bytes[3] = value.toByte()
        return bytes
    }

    override fun toString() = bytesToHex(offset) + " " + bytesToHex(values)

}
```

Can someone please tell me why i.inc() is so much slower than i++?

P.S: Replace client.dll with any file (should be ~12mb to get numbers accurate to mine or simply download my test file here [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/91292881/ShareX/2016/04/2016-04-05_19-24-27.txt)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`inc()` call in your code is completely redundant: it doesn't change the variable:

```
var x = 0
x.inc()
println(x) // 0
```

As to the difference in run time, even the semantics of the two implementations is different:

- First snippet:

  ```
  while (i < data.size) {
      for (j in bytes.indices) {
          bytes[j] = data[i++]
      }
      //...
  }
  ```

  Inner loop changes `i`, so there won't be an iteration of `while` for each `i`, some (even most, I suppose) values of `i` will be skipped.
- Second snippet:

  ```
  for (i in data.indices) {
      for (j in bytes.indices) {
          bytes[j] = data[i] // removed redundant i.inc()
      }
      //...
  }
  ```

  Inner loop is called for each `i` in outer loop, therefore it will take much longer.

Comment: Ah didn't catch that. Thanks!